# Calculate the inverse of a CSS color using CSS only

Tags: css

So in the code below, I have a `--pop` colour, and a `--bg` background color. I wish to calculate a hover color from the two as follows:

Mix `--pop` with the inverse with `--bg`.
e.g. if the background is black, I wish to mix `--pop` with white.
`--bg` could be any color.

```
--pop: #123456;
--bg: black;
--hover: color-mix(in srgb, var(--pop) 30%, ???inverse of --bg here???)
```

Comment: you could try using [invert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/invert) or [blend mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/blend-mode), don't know if that's what your after but there isn't any css functions that will invert a hex for you

Comment: As above, if your elements and structure allow it you may can just set: ````filter: brightness(0) invert(1);````, which just inverts it, but if you need to change items, the JS answer probably is the better approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a CSS only solution from the future using [relative color syntax](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/css-relative-color-syntax/)

```css
--pop: #123456;
--bg: black;
--hover: color-mix(in srgb, var(--pop) 30%, rgb(from var(--bg) calc(1 - r) calc(1 - g) calc(1 - b)))
```

It has no support right now but soon you will be able to test it on Chrome

Answer (score 2):

If the JavaScript solution is okay you can try something like:

```
const inverseColor = (color) => {
    color = color.substring(1);
    color = parseInt(color, 16);
    color = 0xFFFFFF ^ color;
    color = color.toString(16);           // convert to hex
    return `#${(`000000` + color).slice(-6)}`;    // pad with leading zeros
};

let color = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
                .getPropertyValue('--bg');
let inverseBG = inverseColor(color);        

document.documentElement.style
    .setProperty('--bg-inverse', inverseBG);
```

Then

```
--hover: color-mix(in srgb, var(--pop) 30%, var(--bg-inverse));
```